# Why is my React Native application crashing?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I have completed my first RN application. I started building it on a real device and testing it. I basically am plugging it into my mac and building the bundle onto my iPhone. The app works great except when I terminate the app then try to open it by clicking on the app icon. Note: I am not talking about allowing the app to run in the background and pressing on it to bring it to the foreground. I'm terminating it and when trying to run the app it crashes.

I tried lots of different things including adding crash analytics and commenting out code but it seemed like my JavaScript was not a problem.

***Then I decided to create a fresh React Native project, build it to my phone and try it and I got the same issue.***

I feel like I am missing something simple, maybe configuration or something.

***I pulled the error log out of the iPhone and added it below.***

Any assistance would be awesome.

Thanks.

Error Log:

```
{"app_name":"Moder8","timestamp":"2019-02-01 19:59:32.25 -0800","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"ba430d6c-eca6-39fd-b9aa-8f271bb76e8b","adam_id":0,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"net.moder8.Moder8","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.1.3 (16D40)","incident_id":"02913BA2-3C06-45FA-AB1D-7A4A59728DC6","name":"Moder8"}
Incident Identifier: 02913BA2-3C06-45FA-AB1D-7A4A59728DC6
CrashReporter Key:   b859583602856eac3760b6c58731e74b79f3268f
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,2
Process:             Moder8 [635]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6348B6BB-E252-46A0-A494-376ECC36B8B8/Moder8.app/Moder8
Identifier:          net.moder8.Moder8
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           net.moder8.Moder8 [645]


Date/Time:           2019-02-01 19:59:32.0278 -0800
Launch Time:         2019-02-01 19:59:11.9845 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1.3 (16D40)
Baseband Version:    1.03.08
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: net.moder8.Moder8 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.95 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 13.130 (user 13.130, system 0.000), 11% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.081, 0% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002336c9a78 0x2336b1000 + 100984
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000023354e2cc 0x233549000 + 21196
2   CFNetwork                       0x00000002341a22c8 0x2340fb000 + 684744
3   CFNetwork                       0x00000002340ff23c 0x2340fb000 + 16956
4   Moder8                          0x00000001002578d4 0x10012c000 + 1226964
5   Moder8                          0x0000000100257b84 0x10012c000 + 1227652
6   Moder8                          0x0000000100257d94 0x10012c000 + 1228180
7   Moder8                          0x0000000100257e88 0x10012c000 + 1228424
8   Moder8                          0x0000000100258028 0x10012c000 + 1228840
9   Moder8                          0x0000000100132424 0x10012c000 + 25636
10  UIKitCore                       0x000000026180ed3c 0x260ef1000 + 9559356
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000002618104e8 0x260ef1000 + 9565416
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000002618161e0 0x260ef1000 + 9589216
13  UIKitCore                       0x000000026107d51c 0x260ef1000 + 1623324
14  UIKitCore                       0x0000000261086684 0x260ef1000 + 1660548
15  UIKitCore                       0x000000026107d17c 0x260ef1000 + 1622396
16  UIKitCore                       0x000000026107db60 0x260ef1000 + 1624928
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000026107bb14 0x260ef1000 + 1616660
18  UIKitCore                       0x000000026107b7bc 0x260ef1000 + 1615804
19  UIKitCore                       0x0000000261080c0c 0x260ef1000 + 1637388
20  UIKitCore                       0x0000000261081bfc 0x260ef1000 + 1641468
21  UIKitCore                       0x0000000261080ac0 0x260ef1000 + 1637056
22  UIKitCore                       0x0000000261085ccc 0x260ef1000 + 1658060
23  UIKitCore                       0x0000000261814610 0x260ef1000 + 9582096
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000002613e3a70 0x260ef1000 + 5188208
25  FrontBoardServices              0x00000002365d2798 0x2365c5000 + 55192
26  FrontBoardServices              0x00000002365de0e8 0x2365c5000 + 102632
27  FrontBoardServices              0x00000002365dd708 0x2365c5000 + 100104
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000023354d134 0x233549000 + 16692
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000233550728 0x233549000 + 30504
30  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000236614b08 0x2365c5000 + 326408
31  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000236614774 0x2365c5000 + 325492
32  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000236614de0 0x2365c5000 + 327136
33  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000233ad864c 0x233a28000 + 722508
34  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000233ad85c8 0x233a28000 + 722376
35  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000233ad7e80 0x233a28000 + 720512
36  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000233ad2b38 0x233a28000 + 699192
37  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000233ad2418 0x233a28000 + 697368
38  GraphicsServices                0x0000000235d86be8 0x235d7c000 + 44008
39  UIKitCore                       0x0000000261818088 0x260ef1000 + 9597064
40  Moder8                          0x0000000100132884 0x10012c000 + 26756
41  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000233585050 0x233584000 + 4176

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000233754dd0 0x23374b000 + 40400

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000233754dd0 0x23374b000 + 40400

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000233754dd0 0x23374b000 + 40400

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002336c9a3c 0x2336b1000 + 100924
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000233ad8018 0x233a28000 + 720920
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000233ad2c8c 0x233a28000 + 699532
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000233ad2418 0x233a28000 + 697368
4   Foundation                      0x00000002344d63e0 0x2344ce000 + 33760
5   Foundation                      0x00000002344d6284 0x2344ce000 + 33412
6   UIKitCore                       0x000000026190efc8 0x260ef1000 + 10608584
7   Foundation                      0x00000002344d4fc0 0x2344ce000 + 28608
8   Foundation                      0x0000000234611c44 0x2344ce000 + 1326148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000023374c974 0x23374b000 + 6516
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000023374c8d0 0x23374b000 + 6352
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000233754ddc 0x23374b000 + 40412

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000000000000e   x1: 0x0000000000000003   x2: 0x0000000000000028   x3: 0x0000000000000030
    x4: 0x0000000000000507   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000300
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000080001200  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000300000003
   x12: 0x00000000e187142b  x13: 0x000001a26db3dbb9  x14: 0x000000000000001d  x15: 0x000000000000011d
   x16: 0xffffffffffffffdc  x17: 0x00000002648521f8  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000283095ee0
   x20: 0x0000000283095ea0  x21: 0xffffffffffffffff  x22: 0x0000000264797a30  x23: 0x0000000283095ea0
   x24: 0x0000000283da1400  x25: 0x0000000283095f40  x26: 0x000000016fcd13e0  x27: 0x000000016fcd13c0
   x28: 0x000000016fcd13a0   fp: 0x000000016fcd1300   lr: 0x000000023354d824
    sp: 0x000000016fcd12f0   pc: 0x00000002336c9a78 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression`

This error means that your app is taking too long to launch, so iOS has killed your app.

It seems like you are making a **development** build and not a **distribution** build that means the app will require the `metro bundler` to run. If you are making a **distribution** build then the javascript should be bundled into the app so it wouldn't need the `metro bundler`.

## development

A possible reason is that the app no longer has access to the `metro bundler` meaning that when you do a fresh relaunch it searches for the bundler but cannot find it, as your app is taking too long to load (basically it has no javascript) to load. You need to make sure that your `metro bundler` is still running and that the app has access to it.

## distribution

If you are creating a **distribution** build that is by creating an archive and then signing it (probably with an `ad-hoc` profile) then it could be caused by the javascript bundle not having been included into your app. You would need to look over your process for creating an archive to make sure it is correct.

I think it is more likely, seeing as you are having this issue when creating a new project that your problem is that the app cannot reach the `metro bundler`, rather than it being caused by an external dependency like `firebase`, which I have seen cause issues like this due to the `Google-Info.plist` being out of date.

Comment: You are right. I discovered this yesterday when I found the documentation for release builds. I looked for something in React Natives docs prior to this post but was unable to locate it. I guess the name "Running on Device" was not enough for me to catch on it also had build instructions at the bottom of the page.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

Comment: All I had to do was go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Schema -> Info (tab) and change the build config to "Release".

Then replace the following line of code to the AppDelegate -> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];